# failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

При попытке подключить файл с базой я получаю такую ошибку:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  include(./vendor/db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>E:\Programs\OpenServer\domains\test.ru\apanel\login.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include(): Failed opening './vendor/db.php' for inclusion (include_path='.') in <b>E:\Programs\OpenServer\domains\test.ru\apanel\login.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

Сам путь до файла выглядит так:

```
E:\Programs\OpenServer\domains\test.ru\vendor\db.php
```

Подключаю так:

```
include "./vendor/db.php";
```

Как можно это пофиксить?

Comment: Напишите структуру проекта. где относительно login.php находится vendor/db.php

Comment: @АлексейШиманский написано же в ошибке `test.ru\apanel\login.php`

Comment: подключайте не `./` а `../`

Comment: @teran спасибо помогло, как я могу засчитать ваш ответ?

Comment: оформил ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно сообщению об ошбке ваш скрипт находит в папке `E:\Programs\OpenServer\domains\test.ru\apanel\login.php`

вы же включаете `./vendor/db.php` из той же директории, хотя надо подняться на уровень вверх. Т..е в данном случае - использовать не `./` а `../`.

вообще имеет смысл определить в конфиге некоторый набор констант для путей от DOCUMENT_ROOT, в т.ч. а-ля `VENDOR` и использовать их в инклудах.